# How to I break a data frame in pandas into a noncontinuous subset

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning

Lets say I have a pandas dataframe with columns 1-100.
How can I, using indexing, select columns 1-10 and also 30-40 as 1 df?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you may use `.iloc` with positional index of each column. Positional index starts from `0`, so positional index of columns 1 is `0` and columns 10 is `9`. The same for columns 30 is `29` and `40` is 39. You may try as follows:

```
df.iloc[:, list(range(0,10))+list(range(29,40))]
```

Answer (score 1):

Let us do `np.r_`

```
df.iloc[:,np.r_[0:10,29:40]]
```